# Some terminal can't display emoji correctly

Tags: unicode, terminal, emoji

I have several terminals installed. But only some of them can display all Unicode characters correctly. For example, classic emoji symbol  is displayed differently in different terminals:

Xterm
[image: xterm]

Urxvt (aka rxvt-unicode)
[image: urxvt]

Terminology
[image: terminology]

As you can see terminology (and also gnome-terminal or st, which are not present here) can display emoji symbol correctly. urxvt, xterm cannot display rectangle instead of correct character.

Why is it so? locale is same in all terminals. Fonts are obviously installed correctly. xterm and rxvt-unicode should support Unicode (at least czech characters like ěščř display without problems) but they clearly don't support it in 100 %.

Comment: xterm is using a single font (no font-sets), and likely emoji's are not in the font used by xterm.

Comment: @ThomasDickey So there are "multi-font" terminals and terminals which can use one font set only, right?

Comment: I've found this on https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2015-10-04/0/POSTING-en.html :
One important thing to note about XTerm is that you choose a font and then XTerm uses only this font. This might sound a little confusing, yes. Some other terminals work differently: You can specify several fonts, ordered by priority. If the terminal is then asked to display a glyph which is not present in the primary font, it tries to find that glyph in the secondary font, then in the tertiary font, and so on. This is known as “font fallback” or “**fallback fonts**”.

Comment: On the other hand, rxvt-unicode uses font-sets.  So that alone does not explain the question.

Comment: rxvt-unicode also has a problem displaying characters that are too large, this can be worked around by setting URxvt.letterspace: 2 in .Xdefaults, but it makes everything ugly by using up too much space. Some discussion is e.g. here: https://github.com/powerline/fonts/issues/176

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer myself. :-)
There is a thing called **fallback fonts**. These fonts are used when a specific glyph is not present in your main fontset. **Only some terminals support fallback fonts**.

See upper paragraph in this text https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2015-10-04/0/POSTING-en.html and also how to set fallback fonts via fontconfig here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/enable-color-emoji-linux-svg-font